# convert signature algorithm from sha1 to sha256 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, soap, webservice-client

I have a webservice client application. My webservice provider inform me to change the signature method from sha1 to sha256 which is in requests header part. Currently i have a CustomSendFilter class, and securing the outgoing messages with the function below. How can i convert to sha 256? I searched but havent found a definite solution yet.

```
public override void SecureMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
        {
            X509SecurityToken signatureToken;

            signatureToken = new X509SecurityToken(CertificateManager.ClientCertificate);           
          
            security.Tokens.Add(signatureToken);
            
            MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);

            security.Elements.Add(sig);
            security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;

            Logging.AddToLog(envelope.Envelope.InnerText);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the signature algorithm to be used via [`MessageSignature.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedinfo.signaturemethod?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_Xml_SignedInfo_SignatureMethod).

Unfortunately the .NET Framework may not have built-in support for http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 at the time of this writing, but the following code can be used to fix that (credits go to https://gist.github.com/sneal/f35de432115b840c4c1f ):

```
/// <summary>
/// SignatureDescription impl for http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
/// </summary>
public class RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 algorithm
    /// with the .NET CrytoConfig registry. This needs to be called once per
    /// appdomain before attempting to validate SHA256 signatures.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Register()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(
            typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription),
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// .NET calls this parameterless ctor
    /// </summary>
    public RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription()
    {
        KeyAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider";
        DigestAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed";
        FormatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter";
        DeformatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter";
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var asymmetricSignatureDeformatter =
            (AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(DeformatterAlgorithm);
        asymmetricSignatureDeformatter.SetKey(key);
        asymmetricSignatureDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return asymmetricSignatureDeformatter;
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var asymmetricSignatureFormatter =
            (AsymmetricSignatureFormatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(FormatterAlgorithm);
        asymmetricSignatureFormatter.SetKey(key);
        asymmetricSignatureFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return asymmetricSignatureFormatter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for answering. I have a CustomSendFilter class for securing request as below. Where should i register the algorithm? I registered before calling the webservice function  and inside the SecureMessage function below as well but didn't work.

public class CustomSendFilter : SendSecurityFilter
{
private string serviceDescription;

```
    public CustomSendFilter(SecurityPolicyAssertion parentAssertion , string serviceDescription)
        : base(parentAssertion.ServiceActor, true)
    {
        this.serviceDescription = serviceDescription;
    }

    public override SoapFilterResult ProcessMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope)
    {
        SoapFilterResult result = base.ProcessMessage(envelope);

        Logging.SaveSoapEnvelope(envelope, SoapMessageDirection.Out , serviceDescription);

        return result;
    }

    public override void SecureMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
    {
        X509SecurityToken signatureToken;


            signatureToken = new X509SecurityToken(CertificateManager.ClientCertificate);
        RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription.Register();
        security.Tokens.Add(signatureToken);
        
        MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);

        security.Elements.Add(sig);
        security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;

        Logging.AddToLog(envelope.Envelope.InnerText);
    }

}
```